# Physical side key volume button stopped working after upgrading to Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: upgrade, sound, 23.04, volume-control

After upgrading to 23.04, the physical volume buttons on the side panel of the HP EliteBook stopped working. Though audio, volume increase/decrease works fine with <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>/<kbd>F7</kbd> buttons are not recognized by `xev` too.

Comment: 23.04 is going EOL in a few weeks. Upgrade to 23.10 ASAP.